# Multiple search in jqGrid without add/remove button?

Tags: javascript, java, jqgrid, grid, dom-events

Currently I have four filters in my jqGrid with two textboxes and two select boxes.

I want to open pop-up box on click on search button and that popup dialog have all four filters ready on pop-up dialog and should not have any add or remove button on that.

Currently in my code pop-up opens button click but in only have one search filter with add and remove buttons. I don't want add or remove buttons and want all four filters on dialog.

Here is my jqGrid script:

```
`$(document).ready(function () {

    //loadGrid();
    jQuery("#list9").jqGrid({

        height:'100%',
        autowidth: true,
        scrollOffset: 0,
        url:'GridAction',
        mtype: 'GET',
        postData:{requestType:"<%=request.getParameter("request_type")%>",councilDistrictId:"<%=request.getParameter("council_district_id")%>",phoneType:"<%=request.getParameter("phone_type")%>"},
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['S.R ID','Request Type','Council District ID','Council District Name', 'Image', 'Device Type', 'Submission Time', 'Address','Status','Notification Time'],
        colModel:[

            {name:'id',index:'id', align:"center", sortable:true,width:'10%', height: 'auto', search:true},
            {name:'serviceRequestTypeName',index:'serviceRequestTypeName', height: 'auto', align:"center",width:'10%', sortable:true,search:true,stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:"requestDropdownAction",sopt:['eq'],defaultValue:"<%=request.getParameter("request_type")%>"}},
            {name:'councilDistrictId',index:'councilDistrict_Id', align:"center", height: 'auto',width:'5%', sortable:false, search:true,stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:"councilDropdownAction",sopt:['eq'],defaultValue:"<%=request.getParameter("council_district_id")%>"}},
            {name:'councilDistrictName',index:'councilDistrictName', align:"center", height: 'auto',width:'10%',sortable:false, search:false},
            {name:'Image', index:'Image', align:"center",sortable:false, height: 'auto',width:'5%', search:false},
            {name:'deviceType',index:'deviceType', align:"center",sortable:false, height: 'auto',width:'5%',search:true,stype:'select',searchoptions:{value:"All:All;Android:Android;Iphone:Iphone;Web:Web",sopt:['eq'],defaultValue:"<%=request.getParameter("phone_type")%>"}},
            {name:'serviceRequestDate',index:'serviceRequestDate', align:"center", height: 'auto',width:'10%', sortable:true, search:false},
            {name:'serviceRequestAddress',index:'serviceRequestAddress', align:"center", height: 'auto',width:'20%',sortable:true, search:false},
            {name:'serviceRequestStatus',index:'serviceRequestStatus', align:"center", height: 'auto',width:'5%', sortable:false, search:false},        
            {name:'serviceRequestResponseTime',index:'serviceRequestResponseTime', align:"center", height: 'auto',width:'12%', sortable:true, search:false}


        ],
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pager9',
        sortname: 'id',
        recordpos: 'left',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: true,
        toolbarfilter:true,
        caption: false
    });

    //$.extend($.jgrid.search, {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, overlay: 0, searchOnEnter: true, showQuery: true});

    jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager9',{add:false,del:true,edit:false,search:true,position:'right'},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true,overlay:false,multipleGroup: true,
        onClose:function(form){
            // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
            // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
            // the div used by datepicker
            $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
        }});



    jQuery("#m1").click( function() {
        var s;
        s = jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
        alert(s);
    });
    jQuery("#m1s").click( function() {
        jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('setSelection',"13");
    });
    jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true});



});
`
```

here is my jqGrid css:

```
`/*Grid*/
.ui-jqgrid {position: relative; font-size:11px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view {position: relative;left:0px; top: 0px; padding: .0em;}
/* caption*/
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {padding: .3em .2em .2em .3em; position: relative; border-left: 0px none;border-right: 0px none; border-top: 0px none;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-title { float: left; margin: .1em 0 .2em; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close { position: absolute;top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height:18px;}.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close span { display: block; margin: 1px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close:hover { padding: 0; }
/* header*/
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {position: relative; margin: 0em;padding: 0em; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; border-left: 0px none !important; border-top : 0px none !important; border-right : 0px none !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox {float: left;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable {table-layout:fixed;margin:0em; width:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {height:22px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {overflow: hidden; position:relative; height:17px;}
.ui-th-column, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-align:center;border-top : 0px none;border-bottom : 0px none;}
.ui-th-ltr, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-ltr {border-left : 0px none;height:auto;}
.ui-th-rtl, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-rtl {border-right : 0px none;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-div-ie {white-space: nowrap; zoom :1; height:17px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize {height:20px !important;position: relative; cursor :e-resize;display: inline;overflow: hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-grid-ico-sort {overflow:hidden;position:absolute;display:inline; cursor: pointer !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-asc {margin-top:-3px; height:12px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-desc {margin-top:3px;height:12px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-i-asc {margin-top:0px;height:16px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-i-desc {margin-top:0px;margin-left:13px;height:16px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sortable {cursor:pointer;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-search-toolbar th { border-top-width: 1px !important; border-top-color: inherit !important; border-top-style: ridge !important }
tr.ui-search-toolbar input {margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px;height:22px; width:95% !important;}
tr.ui-search-toolbar select {margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px;height:22px; width:95% !important;}
tr.ui-search-toolbar div{padding-right:0px !important; width:auto !important;}
/* body */ 
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {position: relative; margin: 0em; padding:0; overflow: auto; text-align:left;overflow-x:hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable {table-layout:fixed;margin:0em; width:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {font-weight: normal; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre; height: 22px;border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: inherit; border-bottom-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow td {border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup td {font-weight: normal; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre; height: 22px;border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: inherit; border-bottom-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot td {font-weight: bold; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre; height: 22px;border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: inherit; border-bottom-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td {text-align:left;border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: inherit; border-right-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-rtl td {text-align:right;border-left-width: 1px; border-left-color: inherit; border-left-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid td.jqgrid-rownum { margin: 0px; border: 0px none;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize-mark { width:2px; left:0; background-color:#777; cursor: e-resize; cursor: col-resize; position:absolute; top:0; height:100px; overflow:hidden; display:none;  border:0 none;}
/* footer */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sdiv {position: relative; margin: 0em;padding: 0em; overflow: hidden; border-left: 0px none !important; border-top : 0px none !important; border-right : 0px none !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-ftable {table-layout:fixed; margin-bottom:0em;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.footrow td {font-weight: bold; overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap; height: 21px;border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: inherit; border-top-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.footrow-ltr td {text-align:left;border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: inherit; border-right-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.footrow-rtl td {text-align:right;border-left-width: 1px; border-left-color: inherit; border-left-style: solid;}
/* Pager*/
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager { border-left: 0px none !important;border-right: 0px none !important; border-bottom: 0px none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; position: relative; height: 25px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control {position: relative;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table {position: relative; padding-bottom:2px; width:auto; margin: 0em;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table td {font-weight:normal; vertical-align:middle; padding:1px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-button  { height:19px !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-button span { display: block; margin: 1px; float:left;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-button:hover { padding: 0px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-state-disabled:hover {padding:1px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input { height:13px;font-size:.8em; margin: 0em;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-selbox {font-size:.8em; line-height:18px; display:block; height:18px; margin: 0em;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-separator {height: 18px; border-left: 1px solid #ccc ; border-right: 1px solid #ccc ; margin: 1px; float: right;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-paging-info {font-weight: normal;height:19px; margin-top:3px;margin-right:4px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div {padding:1px 0;float:left;list-style-image:none;list-style-position:outside;list-style-type:none;position:relative;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-button { cursor:pointer; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div  span.ui-icon {float:left;margin:0 2px;}
.ui-jqgrid td input, .ui-jqgrid td select .ui-jqgrid td textarea { margin: 0em;}
.ui-jqgrid td textarea {width:auto;height:auto;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager {border-left: 0px none !important;border-right: 0px none !important; border-top: 0px none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; position: relative; height: 25px !important;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;}
/*subgrid*/
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable .ui-sgcollapsed span {display: block;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid {margin:0em;padding:0em; width:100%;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid table {table-layout: fixed;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid tr.ui-subtblcell td {height:18px;border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: inherit; border-right-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: inherit; border-bottom-style: solid;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid td.subgrid-data {border-top:  0px none !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid td.subgrid-cell {border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-subgrid {height:20px;}
/* loading */
.ui-jqgrid .loading {position: absolute; top: 45%;left: 45%;width: auto;z-index:101;padding: 6px; margin: 5px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;display: none;border-width: 2px !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .jqgrid-overlay {display:none;z-index:100;}
* html .jqgrid-overlay {width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+'px');height: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+'px');}
* .jqgrid-overlay iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+'px');height: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+'px');}
/* end loading div */
/* toolbar */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata {border-left: 0px none; border-right: 0px none; height : 21px;overflow: hidden; }
/*Modal Window */
.ui-jqdialog { display: none; width: 300px; position: absolute; padding: .2em; font-size:11px; overflow:visible;}
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar { padding: .3em .2em; position: relative;  }
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-title { margin: .1em 0 .2em; } 
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close { position: absolute;  top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 18px; }

.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close span { display: block; margin: 1px; }
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close:hover, .ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close:focus { padding: 0; }
.ui-jqdialog-content, .ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-content { border: 0; padding: .3em .2em; background: none; height:auto;}
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqconfirm {padding: .4em 1em; border-width:3px;position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:10px;overflow:visible;display:none;height:80px;width:220px;text-align:center;}
/* end Modal window*/
/* Form edit */
.ui-jqdialog-content .FormGrid {margin: 0px;}
.ui-jqdialog-content .EditTable { width: 100%; margin-bottom:0em;}
.ui-jqdialog-content .DelTable { width: 100%; margin-bottom:0em;}
.EditTable td input, .EditTable td select, .EditTable td textarea {margin: 0em;}
.EditTable td textarea { width:auto; height:auto;}
.ui-jqdialog-content td.EditButton {text-align: right;border-top: 0px none;border-left: 0px none;border-right: 0px none; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:5px;}
.ui-jqdialog-content td.navButton {text-align: center; border-left: 0px none;border-top: 0px none;border-right: 0px none; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:5px;}
.ui-jqdialog-content .FormElement {display:block; width:98%; padding:.2em}

.ui-jqdialog-content .CaptionTD {text-align: left; vertical-align: top;border: 0px none; padding: 1px;white-space: normal;}
.ui-jqdialog-content .DataTD {padding: 1px;border-left: 0px none;border: 0px none; vertical-align: top;}
.ui-jqdialog-content .form-view-data {white-space:pre}
.fm-button { display: inline-block; margin:0 4px 0 0; padding: .4em .5em; text-decoration:none !important; cursor:pointer; position: relative; text-align: center; zoom: 1; }
.fm-button-icon-left { padding-left: 1.9em; }
.fm-button-icon-right { padding-right: 1.9em; }
.fm-button-icon-left .ui-icon { right: auto; left: .2em; margin-left: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px; }
.fm-button-icon-right .ui-icon { left: auto; right: .2em; margin-left: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px;}
#nData, #pData { float: left; margin:3px;padding: 0; width: 15px; }
/* End Eorm edit */
/*.ui-jqgrid .edit-cell {}*/
.ui-jqgrid .selected-row, div.ui-jqgrid .selected-row td {font-style : normal;border-left: 0px none;}
/* Tree Grid */
.ui-jqgrid .tree-wrap {float: left; position: relative;height: 18px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .tree-minus {position: absolute; height: 18px; width: 18px; overflow: hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .tree-plus {position: absolute;  height: 18px; width: 18px;  overflow: hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .tree-leaf {position: absolute;  height: 18px; width: 18px;overflow: hidden;}
.ui-jqgrid .treeclick {cursor: pointer;}
/* moda dialog */
.jqmOverlay { background-color: #000; }
* iframe.jqm {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+'px');height: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+'px');}
.ui-jqgrid-dnd tr td {border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: inherit; border-right-style: solid; height:20px}
/* RTL Support */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-title-rtl {float:right;margin: .1em 0 .2em; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox-rtl {float: right; padding-left: 20px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr {float: right;margin: -2px -2px -2px 0px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize-rtl {float: left;margin: -2px 0px -1px -3px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-sort-rtl {left:0px;}
.ui-jqgrid .tree-wrap-ltr {float: left;}
.ui-jqgrid .tree-wrap-rtl {float: right;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-ellipsis {text-overflow:ellipsis; -moz-binding:url('ellipsis-xbl.xml#ellipsis');}
.ui-searchFilter { display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 770; overflow: visible;}
.ui-searchFilter table {position:relative; margin:0em; width:auto}
.ui-searchFilter table td {margin: 0em; padding: 1px;}
.ui-searchFilter table td input, .ui-searchFilter table td select {margin: 0.1em;}
.ui-searchFilter .ui-state-default { cursor: pointer; }
.ui-searchFilter .divider hr {margin: 1px; }

    `
```

can Any one help?